# Understanding buffers/cache in linux `free -m`

Tags: linux, caching, memory, free-command

Just looking for some quick help regarding `free -m` output on Linux. Here's an example on one of my servers:

```
  $free -m
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:         14881      14813         68          0        262        883
  -/+ buffers/cache:      13667       1213
  Swap:         4095        240       3855
```

I understand the kernel can and will use available memory for disk caching to speed up the system.

Normally, I look at the second value in the "free" column, in the above case it's 1213. It's normally a lot higher than this.

I guess I am looking to understand what the two outputs next to '-/+ buffers/cache' mean. From what I can see, the system truly is low on memory (only 1213MB available for applications to use) and the OS actually *needs* 13GB for caching?

Answer (score 14):

This [has been answered](https://serverfault.com/a/85481) in serverfault. Here is the relevant excerpt:

`total` = `used` + `free`

- `shared` / `buffers` / `cached`: This shows memory usage for specific purposes, these values are included in the value for `used`.

The second line gives first line values adjusted. It gives the original value for `used` *minus* the sum `buffers+cached` and the original value for `free` *plus* the sum `buffers+cached`, hence its title. These new values are often more meaningful than those of first line.

[End of excerpt]

Focusing on your situation,

- 14813 (used memory) - 262 (buffered) - 883 (cached) = 13668 (used by applications).

In the event an application needs more memory, it can be taken either from free memory or from cached/buffered, so:

- 262 (buffered) + 883 (cached) + 68 (not used at all) = 1213 (available to applications).

The system does not really *need* 262+883=1145 (not 13GB) for cache and buffers, but since it's there, it takes it (but gives it back if applications need more). Take a look at the [Linux ate my RAM!](http://www.linuxatemyram.com) page.

You can also use `top` (I personally prefer `htop`) to see the memory status and which applications are taking most RAM.

As an example, here is a screenshot of htop running in my RaspberryPi and the `free -h` execution:

[image]

```
raspberry ~ # free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          183M       178M       5,3M         0B        63M        42M
-/+ buffers/cache:        72M       111M
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```